# Using local <image file> for microsoft custom vision

Tags: javascript, microsoft-custom-vision

I'm not sure how to go about this, but I need help in getting my microsoft custom vision to work. I'm using javascript to link my html document to custom vision but I don't know how to use a local image file I have in the same folder as my html and js files, could anybody assist me with any codes?

```
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body
        data: "{body}",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

The instructions tell me to change {body} to

Comment: *the instructions tell me to change {body} to < image file >

Comment: Link for code: https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/450e4ba4d72542e889d93fd7b8e960de/operations/5a6264bc40d86a0ef8b2c290

Comment: I want to use a image file named ‘scam.jpg’

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- The latest API is v3.0 (not 2.0 that you mentioned), see [here](https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Prediction_3.0/operations/5c82db60bf6a2b11a8247c15)
- There is a small error in the code sample they provided on the page: the header key `Prediction-Key` is present 2 times (`key` in uppercase vs lowercase). You just need it 1 time
- You can't directly load a local file in js from a security aspect

So if you want to do it "from scratch", you can do the following, having to choose the file manually:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)' />
    <br />
    <img id='output' style="height:100px; width:100px;" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var openFile = function(file) {
            var input = file.target;

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(){
                var dataURL = reader.result;

                var params = {
                    // Request parameters
                    "application": "myTestApp"
                };

                var parts = dataURL.split(';base64,');
                var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
                var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
                var rawLength = raw.length;

                var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

                for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
                    uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
                }

                var imgContent = new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });

                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v3.0/Prediction/__YOUR_APPLICATION_ID__/classify/iterations/__YOUR_ITERATION_ID__/image?" + $.param(params),
                    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                        // Request headers
                        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Prediction-Key","__YOUR_PREDICTION_KEY__");
                        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    // Request body
                    data: imgContent,
                    processData: false
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    alert("success");
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    alert("error");
                });
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In addition, ou can have a look to existing samples in Node.js here, where they are calling prediction from local files: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-node-sdk-samples/tree/master/Samples/customvision